# Sum of all $x$ satisfying $|x-6| = m$ where $m\in\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I have encountered this question in a book and it had me thinking about a different attempt to solve it, which I think isn't right but can't really comprehend.

Here is the basic way I solve it:

$$x-6 = m \implies x = m+6$$
$$x-6 = -m \implies x = 6-m$$
$$m+6+6-m = 12$$

Answer key also says $12$.

The other way is that we know that $|x-6|>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ except for $x = 6$. Since $m>0$, we can say that the solution set of $x$ is $\mathbb{R}-\{6\}$ and therefore sum of all these values equals $-6$. (As far as I know, summing all $\mathbb{R}$ like this isn't valid. However and unfortunately, it's a commonly used way in solutions in this curriculum, so please ignore that part.)

Is the second way right in any sense? If yes or no please explain it because I couldn't come up with a good explanation other than saying $x$ depends on $m$, therefore it is not right.

Is $m$ a variable or a fixed number? I think it must be a fixed number or else we would end up with infinitely many solutions since it would state a function of $x$. Does $m$ being a variable or a fixed number have any impact on the first question?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $m$ is a fixed number, and your first approach, which abandons any attempt at *elegance* is (in my opinion) **definitely** the algorithm to use.  $m$ is a **fixed** but unknown number.  Further, your paragraph which begins "The other way is that we know..." strikes me as close to being gibberish.  In my opinion, the point of the problem is your willingness to dispense with elegance and **get down in the mud**.

Comment: $m \in \mathbb R^+$ but $m$ is not *any* value in $\mathbb R$.  We are presuming there is *one* particular value that we are being asked about.  (We don't know *what* it is but we do know it is something specific).  So the solutions set is *not* $\mathbb R-\{6\}$.  After all.  $9 \in \mathbb R-\{6\}$ but $x =9$ gives us $|x-6|=|3|=3$.  That is only equal to $m$ if $m$ is $3$ but we don't know $m$ is $3$.  And $53\in \mathbb R-\{6\}$ gives us $|53-6|=47$. Well, $3$ and $47$ can't *BOTH* equal $47$.  Also $m+27\in \mathbb R-\{6\}$.  Bute $|(m+27)-6|=m+21 \ne m$ so that is *NOT* a solution.

Comment: " (As far as I know, summing all R like this isn't valid. However and unfortunately, it's a commonly used way in solutions in this curriculum, so please ignore that part.)"  I'm very saddened to hear that.  That way of summing *isn't* valid and it really *shouldn't* be part of the curriculum.  Yes you can argue that for every $w>0$ there is exactly one $-w<0$ and $w+(-2)=0$ so $\sum_{x\in \mathbb R} x = 0$ but we could just as legally argue that for ever $w>0$ there is exactly one $-2w < 0$ so $\sum_{x\in\mathbb r} x = -\sum_{x\in \mathbb R^+} x = -\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is $m$ a variable or a fixed number?

It's a fixed number.  And unknown fixed number.

> I think it must be a fixed number or else we would end up with infinitely many solutions since it would state a function of x.

It's more that the question just wouldn't make sense.

You'd be expecten so solve for *pairs* of values of $m$ and for $x$.  And so long as $x = \begin{cases}m+6\\6-m\end{cases}$ then $\{(x,m)| x=m+6$ or $x = 6-m; m > 0\}$ would be the set of all *pairs* of solution.

But that wasn't what was asked.  You are asked to suppose $m\in \mathbb R^+$ and so solve for $x$ when $|x-6| = m$.  That is... $m$ is fixed.

> Does m being a variable or a fixed number have any impact on the first question?

Has every impact.